# C++ operator overloading takes pointer type as parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, reference, operator-overloading

I'm new to C++ and trying to figure out the differences between pointer and reference. I've just read [this short summary](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~patrick/csc418/wi2004/notes/PointersVsRef.pdf&ei=5RTNTvWkBMmWiQLyo_jNCw&usg=AFQjCNHAhobym0J_oksOCPFAw2euxyjBOA&sig2=fpcGdCqBP2Z9niiilihS_A).

In the article, the author mentioned that `day *operator++ (day *d);` won't compile (note: `day` is an enum type) and argued that the parameter for this overloaded operator function must be type T, T&, or T const&, where T is a class or enum type.

I assume that pointer is a built-in type rather than a class or enum so it can't be used to overload operators and that operator overloading is not possible for all built-in types such as int and double.

For example, `int i = 1; ++i;` would never result in `i` being 3 by overloading the `++` operator for the type `int`.

Am I correct? Please help me understand this problem better.

Comment: I had a look at the link in your question --- *horrible* (you can already tell from the fact that their example doesn't even compile). The most frequent uses of references are: 1 const references as function arguments when copying the object would be inefficient (and may be disabled by lack of copy constructor); 2 return type for many non-const member functions (including operators); 3 a non-const reference as function argument when the object shall be modified (this usage is debatable as pointers are also popular for that); 4 as data members which can never be changed  (instead of pointer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First rule in Operator overloading is:
You cannot overload operators for built-in data types, You can only for your custom data types, So you are correct in that regard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, pointer are primitive types and not objects. They are just numbers (the memory address of the object they point to), and as such arithmetics can be applied to them.

Yes, you cannot overload operators for primitive types (you can however overload binary operators in a class that take a primitive type parameter).

Comment: Could you please share an example where you want to overload binary operators in a class that take a primitive type parameter?

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng, one example would be a `Complex` class `operator+` which takes a `double` parameter.

Comment: Yep, also it's necessary for `string` concatenation with primitive values (still `operator+`).

I once had to create a Matrix class that had an `operator*` overload with `int` for scalar multiplication.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: Consider this [trivial example](http://codepad.org/257DT8kt) wherein You see overloading of binary operator in a class that takes a primitive type parameter.You can do that because the overloaded function is member function for the custom class,and the inbuilt parameter is just an function argument to this member function.The rule of overloading only for custom types thus holds good here.

Comment: @Viruzzo - Strictly variables of primitive types are also objects, but otherwise you are correct.

Comment: In (usual) sense of "object-oriented objects" (as Wikipedia puts it), they are not.